# Change the name of filename before upload dropzone

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dropzone.js

I want to change name of the filename when file is drop on dropzone.

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

  var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#pop");
  myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {


  });

  myDropzone.on("removedfile",function(file){
   $.ajax({
    url: "delete.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 'name': file.name}
    });
 });

myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
   console.log(file);
  console.log(xhr);console.log(formData);
   file.uniqueName = new Date().getTime() +"_" + file.name;
  formData.append("unicname",  file.uniqueName);
    $("#pop").append("<input type='hidden' name='hidname' id='hidname' value="+file.uniqueName+">");
    xhr.response('unival='+file.uniqueName);
    console.log(xhr);console.log(formData);
    
      console.log(file);
  });

Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
  
     paramName: "file",
  uploadMultiple: true,
    init: function() {
      
     
        thisDropzone = this;
   <!-- 4 -->
        
        $.getJSON('upload.php', function(data) {
    
            <!-- 5 -->
            $.each(data, function(key,value){
                 
                var mockFile = { name: value.name, size: value.size };
                
                myDropzone.options.addedfile.call(myDropzone, mockFile);
 
                myDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(myDropzone, mockFile, "upload/"+value.name);
                 
            });
             
        });
    },

   success: function(file, response){
                
            }

   
};
```

Have already tried the following code but does not work.The values do not append to form data.The changes to variable file are not accessible on dropzone.js from anywhere you definetely can't.
[Dropzone.js](https://rawgit.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.js)

```js
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
   console.log(file);
  console.log(xhr);console.log(formData);
   file.uniqueName = new Date().getTime() +"_" + file.name;
  formData.append("unicname",  file.uniqueName);
    $("#pop").append("<input type='hidden' name='hidname' id='hidname' value="+file.uniqueName+">");
    xhr.response('unival='+file.uniqueName);
    console.log(xhr);console.log(formData);
    
      console.log(file);
  });
```

None of solution does seem to work.
Basically i want to save file to specific filename specified to server.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can change the thumbnail fileName after uploading the file, also I think the dropzone should be separated from your data form, once you upload the file ,the server will return a file name. and you can set a hidden input value with this filename in the data form, then finally submit the data form. the codes are like:

```
<div id="pop">

</div>
<form id="data-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="fileName">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<script>
    var dropzone = new Dropzone("#pop");
    dropzone.on("success",function(file,response){
        var fileName = response.data.fileName //server return fileName
        $('input[name="fileName"]').val(fileName);
        var dataUrl = response.data.fileUrl;
        file.name = fileName //change thumbnail file name
        this.emit("thumbnail",file,dataUrl);//draw thumbnail
    });

</script>
```

Comment: This will not change the file name on browser side i.e. alt attribute for the image which i need to change here

Comment: the file name you are talking about i think is the thumbnail file name in dropzone 's terminology. however, please see my updates in the codes.

Answer (score 0):

you also need following css to go with js codes to achieve your result:

```
.dz-preview .dz-filename{display:none}
.dz-preview.dz-success .dz-filename{display:block}
```